# Issue with Attr binding in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout attr binding for data- attributes, like :

```
 <div data-bind="attr : { 'data-fire': Fire, 'data-age': Age }">
 </div>
```

Now what i want is that if any observable varibale i.e. `Fire and Age` is null or empty than i do not want to add an empty attribute name. So after applying binding if suppose `Age` is empty than i do not want my markup to be :

```
 <div data-bind="attr : { 'data-fire': Fire, 'data-age': Age }"  data-age data-fire="Yes">
 </div>
```

Instead i want to remove data-age and want this clean markup :

```
 <div data-bind="attr : { 'data-fire': Fire, 'data-age': Age }" data-fire="Yes">
 </div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this in knockout.js?

Comment: What is the problem with the empty attributes, by the way?

Comment: it increases markup size unnecessarily

Comment: Custom binding is probably what you want then. Updated answer.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem because by default if your observables (Fire, Age) are returning `null` or `undefined` KO doesn't emit the bound empty attribute...

Answer (score 1):

You can control this yourself using [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html):

```
<div data-bind="addAttributes : { 'data-fire': Fire, 'data-age': Age }"></div>
```

Then have a handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    }
};
```

In these methods, you can check the values and add the attributes in manually (using jQuery, for example) only if the values aren't blank.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, but that was just a typo, i updated by question

Comment: Yeah, just saw, there were a lot of edits whilst I was typing my answer out! Why is the empty attribute a problem?